# iOS - Updating auto layout constraint constant stops working after pushing another view controller then returning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a UIViewController designed in IB (Storyboard) that has a UIView containing a few controls. The UIView has an auto layout constraint to fix its height.  In my UIViewController subclass I have an `IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint` (ivar) wired to the height constraint so that I can adjust it in code.  Depending on user events, I expand/shrink the height of the UIView by modifying the constraint's `constant` property between 80 and 44, which also slides up/down a UITableView which is constrained to the bottom of the UIView. I have used this technique before and all works well.

I am now using 4 instances of this UIViewController within a parent container UIViewController with a UITabBar.  When the UITabBar tab selection is changed, I swap in the appropriate instance using `insertSubView`.  The problem is that the UIView fails to expand/shrink in the first child view controller tab page. In the other 3 tab page instances it works fine.  Also in the 3 tab pages where it works, if I push another view controller onto the stack and then return back, the resizing of the UIView no longer works.

In the case where the expand/shrink fails, I have used `NSLog` to monitor the value of the constraint's `constant` property and it is being changed in every instance, but the height of the UIView is not being affected.  As if the constraint is no longer set to work on the UIView??

I'm using Xcode 5.1 and my app is targetting iOS7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved this problem by changing the code within the `animateWithDuration` block which calls `layoutIfNeeded` on the container control to refresh the position of the controls.  Basically instead of just calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the parent container control, I now call `layoutIfNeeded` on each of the child controls whose position will change due to the constraint constant being modified.  Now all controls reposition correctly on all 4 tab pages and even after returning from another view controller.

Comment: Thanks for this. Were you able to figure out what is causing this? It seems as if Auto-Layout just stops laying out after dismissing. In my case, I was pushed on a navigation controller, then presented a modal view controller (`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`). Upon pressing Cancel. It is as if Auto-Layout stops working.

I know that when pushed onto a nav controller, your view controller won't receive `viewWillAppear:` when dismissing a modal view controller. Not sure if that is related to Auto-Layout just stopping.

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately I still can't see any reason why it just stops working.  As far as I'm concerned we shouldn't be seeing this, and my answer is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this. This still seems the case using iOS7.1 from code built with xcode 6.3. Not a nice workaround, but it works and this has been driving me nuts.